# order an entity list referenced with DBRef with spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following model and I am using Spring Data MongoDB

```
@Document(collection="sections")
class Section {

  @Id
  String final id

  @DBRef(lazy = true)
  private List<Block> blocks;
}

@Document(collection="blocks")
class Block {
  @Id
  String final id;
}
```

in mongo this creates the following structure (an example)

```
{
 "_id" : "1",
 "blocks" : [
             DBRef("blocks", "block1"),
             DBRef("blocks", "block2"),
             DBRef("blocks", "block3")
            ]
},
```

Now, I would like to order the blocks in a section without fetching the blocks.
I mean a section is exposed via a rest endpoint and making the following order request I wouldn't want to fetch the individual block documents.

```
PATCH /sections/1 -d '{"block3":1, "block2":3, "block1":2}'
```

after this the document structure should be:

```
{
 "_id" : "1",
 "blocks" : [
             DBRef("blocks", "block3"),
             DBRef("blocks", "block1"),
             DBRef("blocks", "block2")

            ]
},
```

How can I do that with Spring Data MongoDB?

Comment: Did you get answer to this? @Zoltan